# Retrofit 2.3 идет по методу onFailure

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
        App.getApi().getData("e9693a724b2cff4dfde5fc39f9bc85a6", 1, 3, "it").enqueue(new Callback<List<Artist>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Artist>> call, Response<List<Artist>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mArtistList.addAll(response.body());
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "server is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Artist>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error with query",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

в методе асинхронного запроса, retrofit приходит сразу к методу onFailure, почему это может быть? сервер отвечает по запросу api, могут быть некоторые проблемы с моделью, может это быть причиной?

---

```
 "message": {
    "header": {
        "status_code": 200,
        "execute_time": 0.0046639442443848
    },
    "body": {
        "artist_list": [
            {
                "artist": {
                    "artist_id": 31973763,
                    "artist_mbid": "",
                    "artist_name": "Rkomi",
                    "artist_name_translation_list": [],
                    "artist_comment": "",
                    "artist_country": "",
                    "artist_alias_list": [],
                    "artist_rating": 69,
                    "primary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": [
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 18,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                                    "music_genre_name": "Hip Hop/Rap",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Hip Hop/Rap",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "Hip-Hop-Rap"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "secondary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": []
                    },
                    "artist_twitter_url": "",
                    "artist_vanity_id": "Rkomi",
                    "artist_edit_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Rkomi?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=A1",
                    "artist_share_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Rkomi",
                    "artist_credits": {
                        "artist_list": []
                    },
                    "restricted": 0,
                    "managed": 0,
                    "updated_time": "2016-07-09T16:47:34Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "artist": {
                    "artist_id": 33111847,
                    "artist_mbid": "b8a7c51f-362c-4dcb-a259-bc6e0095f0a6",
                    "artist_name": "Ed Sheeran",
                    "artist_name_translation_list": [],
                    "artist_comment": "",
                    "artist_country": "GB",
                    "artist_alias_list": [
                        {
                            "artist_alias": "エド シーラン"
                        },
                        {
                            "artist_alias": "ai de xi lan"
                        },
                        {
                            "artist_alias": "Ed shiran"
                        }
                    ],
                    "artist_rating": 100,
                    "primary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": [
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 10,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                                    "music_genre_name": "Singer/Songwriter",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Singer/Songwriter",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "Singer-Songwriter"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "secondary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": []
                    },
                    "artist_twitter_url": "https://twitter.com/edsheeran",
                    "artist_vanity_id": "Ed-Sheeran",
                    "artist_edit_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Ed-Sheeran?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=A1",
                    "artist_share_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Ed-Sheeran",
                    "artist_credits": {
                        "artist_list": []
                    },
                    "restricted": 0,
                    "managed": 0,
                    "updated_time": "2017-04-28T22:35:37Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "artist": {
                    "artist_id": 31952579,
                    "artist_mbid": "",
                    "artist_name": "Ghali",
                    "artist_name_translation_list": [],
                    "artist_comment": "",
                    "artist_country": "",
                    "artist_alias_list": [],
                    "artist_rating": 82,
                    "primary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": [
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 18,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                                    "music_genre_name": "Hip Hop/Rap",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Hip Hop/Rap",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "Hip-Hop-Rap"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 21,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                                    "music_genre_name": "Rock",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Rock",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "Rock"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 1068,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 18,
                                    "music_genre_name": "Alternative Rap",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "Hip Hop/Rap / Alternative Rap",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "Hip-Hop-Rap-Alternative-Rap"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "secondary_genres": {
                        "music_genre_list": [
                            {
                                "music_genre": {
                                    "music_genre_id": 50000064,
                                    "music_genre_parent_id": 34,
                                    "music_genre_name": "French Pop",
                                    "music_genre_name_extended": "French Pop",
                                    "music_genre_vanity": "French-Pop"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "artist_twitter_url": "",
                    "artist_vanity_id": "Ghali-2",
                    "artist_edit_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Ghali-2?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=A1",
                    "artist_share_url": "https://www.musixmatch.com/artist/Ghali-2",
                    "artist_credits": {
                        "artist_list": []
                    },
                    "restricted": 0,
                    "managed": 0,
                    "updated_time": "2016-06-24T14:49:40Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

по сути мне надо вывести список исполнителей, я запихиваю json в http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org и там вылезает куча классов, а в интерфейсе с методом запроса нужно указать один тип метода запроса, вот мне кажется здесь что-то и не сходится

Comment: что приходит в параметре Throwable t?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych честно говоря не знаю( это может быть причиной? по сути эти методы были сгенерированы внутренним анонимным классом, даже не задумался о Throwable t

Comment: @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Artist>> call, Throwable t) {
Log.e("error", t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error with query",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: в t приходит вот что java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: пояснить ошибку или самому стало понятно?

Comment: Лучше бы пояснить конечно

Comment: у тебя метод расчитивает получить от сервера массив сущностей Artist (ответ от сервера должен начинатся с квадратной скобки), а тебе приходит от сервера jsonobject (ответ от сервера начинатся с фигурной скобки). вот и причина почему у тебя всегда onFailure. покажи ответ от сервера?

Comment: привышение длины сообщения, могу в ответ кинуть

Comment: отправь на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com либо редактируй свой вопрос